# Where is this Javascript event handler argument defined?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

My question is about this html code (I am working in Chrome 56).

```html
<html> 
<body> 
<input type='range' min='0' max='5' step='0.1' oninput="console.log(value)">
</body> 
</html>
```

This code works as expected -- moving the slider control leads to a bunch of values being printed to the console.

Apparently a `value` variable is defined in the scope in which `console.log(value)` is run.  My main question is, where does this `value` variable come from?  Also, are there other variables like it that are "just there?"  Is there documentation for such variables, and is it good practice to rely on them being there?

Comment: it refers to the input field "value" attribute, also "this" would refer to the html tag itself and pass all its values, you can pass in any html attribute including "event" -data

Comment: Ok but why/how?  It looks like an "implicit `this`" which I did not think JS had.  Is this behavior part of Javascript, or is it something extra done by the browser?

Comment: http://jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html

Comment: "Modern browsers augment the FunctionBody's scope chain with the element..."  Aha!  This ref answered the rest of my question, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the callback is done within the context of your input field. The "value" variable is actually, then, that input's "value" attribute, equivalent to `this.value` ...

Which brings us to your second question: you want to see what other attributes "this" has in this context? Try this in your handler:

```
oninput="console.log(this)"
```

Your developer console will spit out an object that you can then inspect.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What lets me I write `console.log(value)` instead of being forced to write `console.log(this.value)`?

Comment: That's just how variable scope in javascript works. If you were to define `var value = 'nothing';` then that would become your current "value" variable. But since there's no local variable defined in your handler, it looks to "this" for context. In this case "this" is the input field. You could also try and access the window's "value" attribute (which won't exist unless you set it yourself) with `console.log(window.value)`

Comment: Sounds like an implicit `this` (as in C++) which I thought Javascript did not have. I could not find a reference explaining that JS "looks to `this` for context," any pointers?  Still feels to me like the browser itself is performing an extra step (not part of pure JS) of copying `this` attributes into the handler's scope -- but can't find a ref for this either.

Comment: This article, I think, explains it well: http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Comment: My early searches hit on this article, and several other good art's on scope and context in JS, but I did not see any of them making the point of scope chain augmentation by the browser as explicitly as the jibbering ref above does.